# After configuring a Linux kernel, can I safely make bzImage and modules at the same time?

Tags: linux, kernel, make

I noticed that my processors were, in total, in use only about 50% of the time while making a Linux kernel.

I usually make the kernel, then make the modules.

I have just started a make bzImage in one terminal and a make modules in another and see that both my processors are in full use. I expect the total compile time will be a lot quicker as I'm compiling in parallel instead of serial.

Are there any "gotya's" that make this unsafe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `make -j 3` and it should compile in paralell, and will ensure any dependencies are properly handeled, this is the "official" way to do it.

Comment: on a two-core system (50% utilization suggests this) -j 2 would be a better idea. With -j 3, system constantly forced to context changes by enforcing 3 jobs on 2 processor threads. BTW the questioner's correct answer is "make -j 2 bzImage modules"

Comment: @asdmin - Because of the way make does paralellism, with <= 4 cores it's better to do N+1, above that there's not as much benefit as IO becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

And no, you should not start building two objects in the same directory that are likely to try and compile the same code at the same time.